# Error observed while configuring logstash forwarder

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

While trying to configure the logstash forwarder on the central server, below error is observed in `logstash.log`:

```
 {:timestamp=>"2015-07-07T09:05:14.742000-0500", :message=>"Unknown setting 'timestamp' for date", :level=>:error}
 {:timestamp=>"2015-07-07T09:05:14.744000-0500", :message=>"Error: Something is wrong with your configuration."}
```

Could someone please help to resolve this issue?

Here is the configuration file:`/etc/logstash/conf.d/central.conf`:

```
input {
    lumberjack {
        port => 6782
        ssl_certificate => "/etc/logstash/server.crt"
        ssl_key => "/etc/logstash/server.key"
        type => "lumberjack"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { }
    elasticsearch {
        cluster => "logstash"
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) This has nothing to do with logstash-forwarder; (2) Post the date{} stanza(s) from your logstash config.

Comment: date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }